# Creating long forms in Bootstrap to be all one form, instead of multiple forms

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to create a long form that is just all one form instead of a bunch of separate forms. Is this doable? I've reviewed all the Bootstrap Documentation and this seems to be the only way to do it. Does anyone know a way around this? Below is what I have, every field is a separate form, and I need it to be one.

```
<div class="row-container">

           <div class="row">
               <div class="field-wrapper">
               <form class="form-inline">
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="claimnumber">Claim Number</label>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="claimnumber" placeholder="">
                   </div>

               </form>
               </div>

               <div class="field-wrapper">
               <form class="form-inline">
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="insuredid">Insured ID</label>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="insuredid" placeholder="">
                   </div>

               </form>
               </div>

               <div class="field-wrapper">
               <form class="form-inline">
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="claimnumber">Patient ID</label>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="patientid" placeholder="">
                   </div>

               </form>
               </div>

               <div class="field-wrapper">
               <form class="form-inline">
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="lastname">Patient Last Name</label>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="">
                   </div>

               </form>
               </div>

               <div class="field-wrapper">
               <form class="form-inline">
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="lastname">Patient Last Name</label>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Text1" placeholder="">
                   </div>

               </form>
               </div>

           </div>
        </div>

        <div class="datecontainer">
            <div class="date1container">
                <div class="dateheading">Service Date</div>
                <div class="datebody">
                   <div class="field-wrapper">
               <form class="form-inline">
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="lastname">Start</label>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control calendar" id="date" placeholder="00/00/0000">
                   </div>

               </form>
               </div>
                   <div class="field-wrapper">
               <form class="form-inline">
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="lastname">End</label>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control calendar2" id="date2" placeholder="00/00/0000">
                   </div>

               </form>
               </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="date2container">
                <div class="dateheading">Import Date</div>
                <div class="datebody">
                   <div class="field-wrapper">
               <form class="form-inline">
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="lastname">Start</label>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control calendar3" id="date3" placeholder="00/00/0000">
                   </div>

               </form>
               </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with just one form... check this

http://jsfiddle.net/7LChZ/1/show/

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="row-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="field-wrapper">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="claimnumber">Claim Number</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="claimnumber" placeholder="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field-wrapper">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="insuredid">Insured ID</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="insuredid" placeholder="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field-wrapper">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="claimnumber">Patient ID</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="patientid" placeholder="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field-wrapper">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="lastname">Patient Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field-wrapper">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="lastname">Patient Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Text1" placeholder="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="datecontainer">
            <div class="date1container">
                <div class="dateheading">Service Date</div>
                <div class="datebody">
                    <div class="field-wrapper">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="lastname">Start</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control calendar" id="date" placeholder="00/00/0000" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field-wrapper">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="lastname">End</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control calendar2" id="date2" placeholder="00/00/0000" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="date2container">
                <div class="dateheading">Import Date</div>
                <div class="datebody">
                    <div class="field-wrapper">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="lastname">Start</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control calendar3" id="date3" placeholder="00/00/0000" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

What I change is, I remove all form tags and wrap them all with just one.

Answer (score 0):

You should only use one `<form>` -tag and not multiple ones if you only need one form. You should place it after `<div class="row">`. And don't forget to close it correctly!

Comment: Are you familiar with Bootstrap? The `<form class= ""> </form>` is what gives the field it's styling, which means they have to be separate forms for each field, making this option not usable. Am I misunderstanding how it works?

Comment: Yeah, I am. I have running 3 web sites running bootstrap. Your question shows me, that you have not much experience with HTML. Bootstraps helps you to work with html but you need still to know what you do. the `<form>`-tag explains: this is a form. The `class="form-inline"` will still feel well putted right after the `<div>`-tag as mentioned in my answer. Just try it.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, so just to clarify, I would leave the `<form class=""> </form>` as is, and just add a `<form></form>' around the div "row"?

I appreciate your help!